# Как сохранить gif изображение из поста Вконтакте на сервер? PHP

Tags: php, вконтакте, api, gif

Как сохранить например это .gif изображение к себе на сервер?
https://psv4.userapi.com/c816137/u17148100/docs/838904d1498e/Bob.gif

Мой нерабочий код:

```
$url = 'https://psv4.userapi.com/c816137/u17148100/docs/838904d1498e/Bob.gif';
$path = 'image.gif';
file_put_contents($path, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy($url, '/path/to/file.gif')`
Документация: [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php).

В случае, если первый вариант не сработал, можно попробовать это:

```
<?php
call($url); // кидает запрос на указанный URL с пользовательским 
// юзерагентом, без этого для ВК не работает.

if (copy($url), './test.gif')) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
   print_r( error_get_last() );
 }

function call($url, $post = null, $_hash = null) {
        if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36');
            if($post) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
            }
            $out = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return ($out);
        }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Этот код также не работает с ссылками ВК

Comment: Всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: <?php
if(!@copy('https://psv4.userapi.com/c816137/u17148100/docs/838904d1498e/Bob.gif','./somefile.gif'))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
?>

Comment: Потому что указываете ссылку на несуществующий файл.

Comment: Но как мне получить ссылку на gif в ВК? Если они в итоге получаются недоступными. Ссылку брал из открытого альбома..

Comment: А мне откуда знать каким образом вы её берёте? Подробнее расскажите.

Comment: Просто захожу в любую открытую группу и копирую прямую ссылку на .gif

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82171/discussion-between-ya-ymer-and-coffee-intime).

Comment: Здравствуйте еще раз, не подскажите как можно узнать размер gif в вконтакте без ее скачивания?

Comment: @CoffeeinTime здравствуйте. Если без скачивания, то через [API](https://vk.com/dev/docs.getById). В результате выполнения возвращается [Doc-объект](https://vk.com/dev/doc), где `size` - размер в байтах.